# YouTube Data API v3 - How to manage default API quota while needing to send requests every 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Lately I've been struggling with an issue of managing the usage of a default API quota of YouTube Data API V3 (10 000 daily requests).
In my JS app I need to request for the subscribers and concurrent watchers count every 60 seconds, while having only the channel ID. Therefore here are the two steps I'm performing:
1. Use the channel ID to fetch Subscribers count and the Live stream ID:

```
function show_yt_subs(room, youtube_id){

//var envelope = Object.values(JSON.parse(msg))[0];
console.log('[DEBUG] YT_SUBS Request - YT ID: %s.', youtube_id);
// Replace id and key with the accountId and an API key.


// Replace id and key with the accountId and an API key.
var id = youtube_id;
var yt_streamid;

var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" + id + "&key=" + key;

request({
method: 'GET',
url: url
}, function (err, response, text) {
if (err) {

    return;
}

var json = JSON.parse(text);
if (json.error) {
    console.log('[DEBUG]YT API Error: ' +JSON.stringify(json.error.errors));
    return;
}
if (!json.items) { 
console.log('[DEBUG]YT_SUBS unavailable. Check your YouTube ID in Preferences tab.');
return; 
} else {
var yt_subs = json.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
console.log(yt_subs);
io.to(room).emit('yt_subs', yt_subs);
show_yt_streamid(room, youtube_id);
}
});
}
```

2. After obtaining the current Live Stream ID, fetch the concurrent watchers and likes count:

```
function show_yt_stats(room, yt_streamid){
var key = "##############";
console.log('[DEBUG] YT_STATS Request - YT ID: %s.', yt_streamid);
/*var data = buildApiRequest('GET',
            '/youtube/v3/videos',
            {'id': youtube_id,
             'part': 'snippet,statistics,liveStreamingDetails'}); */
var api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+yt_streamid+'&part=snippet,statistics,liveStreamingDetails&key=' + key;
request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: api_url,

}, function (err, response, data) {
if (err) {

    return;
}
var data = JSON.parse(data);
var getStreamTitle = data.items[0].snippet.title;
var getStreamLikes = data.items[0].statistics.likeCount;
var getStreamViews = data.items[0].liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers;

console.log('[DEBUG] Information received: ');
console.log('[DEBUG] Title: %s - LikesCount: %s - Views: %s.', getStreamTitle, getStreamLikes, getStreamViews);
console.log('[DEBUG] Emitting YT_STATS to room: %s', room);
io.to(room).emit('yt_stats', JSON.stringify({"yt_title":getStreamTitle,"yt_watchers":getStreamViews, "yt_likes":getStreamLikes}));
return;});
```

Both these functions run every 60 seconds. That gives two requests every minute per user. If the user is streaming for about 6 hours, it'll give us about 720 requests per user, per usual stream. While keeping up with such quota usage (with, let's say, 10 users), it'll get dry after less than 2 hours.
Now, I understand that one of the solutions here would be to extend the default quota, but at the same time I am wondering if there is another way to keep up with the default daily quota and provide myself with the data above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is any other way around what you are doing.  Quota is quota if you need the data then you need to use your quota.

**Request extension**

You should considered requesting an extension of your quota.

[image]

Click the pencil icion

[image]

Click apply for higher quota and fill out the form.  It can take a while to hear back you may have to pay for the extended quota but they will normally work with you.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, DaImTo. I was also thinking about the possibility of using the OAuth instead of API (yet trying my best to avoid that, because I'd like my project to be as safe for the end user as possible and therefore make the usage of YouTube data read-only). Would it be possible though to request such data with OAuth and without using the API-key-related quota limitation entirely?
Also, could you tell me a little more about your experiences with applying for higher quota?

Comment: You could use Oauth2 to access the data and request access of a user.  However i dont see how this would change anything the quota limits are the same.   Applying for higher quota can take time but it depends upon the api and how buzy they are any where from two weeks to two months.  Most of the time you just get upgraded and never hear from Google.  However with the YouTube API you may hear from them.